# Screen_Off does not work in Application Level

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Screen_Off does not work in application Level ,although it is working on Activity Level.

My Problem,when Screen goes off,it must go to Login screen,below code ,successfully go to Login screen but it cause me unregistered Receive Broadcast

what i have did

if l do in Menifesty level,Screen off broadcast does not fire,

Manifest Level

```
          <receiver android:name="com.android.libray.ScreenReciver" android:enabled="true" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
             </intent-filter>
      </receiver>


if i do in activity level,then it will fire screenReciver


  IntentFilter filter =new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

            BroadcastReceiver mReceiver=new ScreenReciver();
                registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

public class ScreenReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                // do whatever you need to do here

             Intent myintent = new Intent(context,TimerClockActivity.class);
                myintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                myintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(myintent);
                wasScreenOn = false;
             Log.v("screenoff", "Logggoff");

            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                // and do whatever you need to do here

            }


    }
```

}

Comment: Have you implemented your Application class. Try extending application class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SCREEN_OFF` Broadcast is a protected broadcast, and you will only receive it if you register dynamically through Java code in a Service or Activity or another Receiver. Registering in the manifest doesn't work for this broadcast.

Comment: but problem ,i have unregister Recigver

Comment: i do not want to unregister reciver at each activity level

Comment: @saqib You only need to register and unregister it once.

Comment: let us suppose you have more than three activity,you register and unregister in login screen. you move in third activity,screen_off call is called then error is occured ,you do not unregister .can you tell me how can i solve this

Comment: @saqib Make a base Activity which registers and unregisters your receiver, and inherit your three Activities from that.